# Product over a range

Tags: c++, for-loop, range

I'm trying to write a little loop for this

[image]

Where Pi is the (if you're not aware, just being thorough) products of the argument over the range of k. Sorta like the summation sign. Anyway, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to write this. I've written this little function but it isn't what I want. It's just printing the result of the (7i - 2) over the range I've specified. It isn't multiplying them all together, I know I haven't asked it to do that. I'm not even sure *how* to ask it to do that. Looking for hints, not necessarily an answer (though, that would be nice too).

What I've done so far:

```
void prod(long int& num)
{
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 25; ++i)
    {
        num =(-1.0)*((7.0*i - 2));

        std::cout << num << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::accumulate` (and I suppose a `boost::irange` works well for the numbers).

Comment: @Matt, I just added some notes on this, hope it helps.  You may want to check your numerical values for k = 25.  What values were you using?  By the way,  what is your application for this function?  Just curious.

Comment: @bruce3141 yeah, read your notes, see my comment on them. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt, ok cool, hope it helps. For reference I added a recursive solution for small k (as discussed in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = 1;    
for (int i=1; i <= 25; ++i)
{
    num *= ((7.0*i - 2));
    std::cout << -num << std::endl;
}
num *= -1;
std::cout << num << std::endl;
```

Subtle differences.

The `*=` operator works like this....

```
A *= B;
```

is exactly the same as writing this...

```
A = A * B;
```

It multiplies the value on the left by the value on the right and assigns it to the value on the left.

You can do the same thing with all the math operators: `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, and `%=`.

---

EDIT: As a note, and as properly pointed out by `bruce3141`'s answer, both the `int` and `long long` data types will result in an overflow before you get to `k = 25`, so as it stands, while this algorithm IS correct, it will not give you correct results in a computer due to overflow.  Using a floating point data type such as `double` isn't an acceptable solution really.  You'll need to look into a class that can handle integers larger than what `long long` will store.  I'm not sure what `C++` has, but you're looking for something that is the equivalent of `Java`'s `BigInteger` class.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Can you link me the `*=` in the C++ documentation by chance? Thanks again.

Comment: Damn. I was hoping there would be something comparable to the Python docs (I'm new to C++). Thanks again!

Comment: [C++ operator summary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators), and more to the point [the assignment operator family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment). And that site, btw, is *the* site for your C++ language inquiries. Bookmark it.

Comment: @Matt this is a good answer, if all your program needs to do is calculate the value for the above expression alone

Comment: @gldraphael It's all he asked about.  If he needs to calculate for a different `k`, I'm sure he can figure it out.  And if he can't, he can post a question asking about that.  That's a relatively trivial matter... and not what the posted question is asking about.

Comment: that's what I've trying to explain in the comments of my answer too! The OP can change it the way he wants to, I only posted a suggested solution that would work and be sufficient for most situations

Comment: @gldraphael Your answer is a drastic divergence from the OP's original function and doesn't sufficiently explain the changes you've made (for example, switching to a floating point data type).

Comment: LOL let @Matt judge, I only gave a suggestion, and I don't think you are doing any good to the community by fighting for what is right and what is not. The OP has posted what he did so far. He dint ask us to modify it. He instead wanted us to give him a possible solution for how the expression could be solved, my answer targeted the OP's target, not his code

Comment: @gldraphael He already has decided.  He voted for my answer.  If your answer was acceptable but perhaps simply not preferred by Matt, I'd leave it be.  The problem is, your solution suggests that floating point and integer data types are just interchangeable, and if you ever think you might get a number larger than an int to hold, it's acceptable to just switch over and use a double.  But this is about as wrong as it gets.  There are DRASTIC differences between floating point and integer data types.  You can't just use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting problem at a couple of levels but there are some issues that need to be pointed out.  First of all the algorithm posted by nhgrif is correct (and was accepted as such) but keep in mind that for the given "product" function, both the "int" and "long" return values overflow quite quickly, so the code never actually gives the right answer for k = 25.  In fact, for the int type, the said algorithm only gives the correct answer up to k = 7 which is 1838865600 (on my machine).  Afterward, for k >= 8, the numerical values are incorrect.

This can be see by running nhgrif's algorithm with the output of the prod() function displayed say for up k = 10:

```
i = 1: -5
i = 2: -60
i = 3: -1140
i = 4: -29640
i = 5: -978120
i = 6: -39124800
i = 7: -1838865600
i = 8: -2147483648
i = 9: -2147483648
i = 10: -2147483648
.
.
.
```

From the above we see that the max value (in magnitude) for int is quickly reached at i = 8, which can be checked by running:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{    
    int maxInt = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::cout << "max: " << maxInt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

giving the expected value:

```
max: 2147483647
```

We also see that for the long data type we have the same issue but can make it up to k = 12, until the limit for long is hit at k = 13, which is: -9223372036854775808.

Bottom line is that the posted code above gives the wrong answer for the value of k = 25 originally requested by Matt.

The solution is to use a string representation for numbers.  Such string representations are commonly used for large numbers beyond the limits of ordinary data types (e.g., the # of Rubik's cube states or the # of atoms in a gram of carbon). But I think this could take a little thinking since the calculation would need to be represented as an operation on strings, to avoid dealing with ints and longs directly.

Interestingly, the function given by Matt sums directly to a closed-form solution for arbitrary k:

[image]

expressed in terms of the Gamma function, which would require some extra code to define in C++ (but C++ 11 has it defined).

For reference, for k = 25 the answer for Matt's prod() function is:
-6472463290438308956636841782995191201792000000

For what its worth, you can also write the algorithm recursively:

```
#include <iostream>

long prod(int k);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int k = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << ": " << -prod(i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

long prod(int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
    return 5;
    }
    else {
        return (7*k - 2)*prod(k - 1);
    }
}
```

But this code also has the same overflow problems discussed above.

Comment: That's a lot to take in. My `i` max was set arbitrarily and not necessarily needed for my problem. But this is good to know. My actual assignment had this (interestingly enough) within a summation function. I'm supposed to prove/disprove that the entire expression is equivalent to another function for arbitrarily large values of a separate variable `n`. That is another issue altogether...aka...lots of work.

Comment: @Matt Just as a note, while `k = 25` will result in an overflow for both `int` and `long long`, using the `double` data type (which isn't suggested here) is absolutely wrong.  `Java` offers the `BigInteger` class, and other programming languages has similar options, but I'm not sure what `C++` has.  If there's nothing built into the language, there's almost certainly a library that would be available for download where someone has already optimized a class for storing integers larger than what `long long` can hold.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `num` to 1, then put this in the `while`:

`num = num*((7.0*i - 2));`

Multiply it by `-1` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
double prod(unsigned int k)
{
    double result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= k; i ++)
    {
        result * = 7*i - 2;
    }
    return -result;
}
```

You can use it as:

```
std::cout<<prod(25);
```

How it works:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= k; i ++)
    {
        result * = 7*i - 2;
    }
```

calculates the pi part of your expression
Since -1 is out of the pi expression I multiply the result by -1 only once and then return it in the return statement:

```
return -result;
```

EDIT:

Every mathematical expression (where there are no unknowns) will always be equal-to a single value. So it's better to represent that expression by making the function return the expression's value. Returning a value makes the function more re-usable than just printing the value to the console.
*for eg. I can do something like* `double x = prod(3) + prod(4);`

Since there's one unknown (the upper limit k), I take it as a parameter to the function so that the code can be used with different upper values of k.

It's always good to follow good designing patterns to avoid wasting time by re-factoring your code later on.

Comment: This is wrong on several levels... the original problem is using a `void` function and only uses `int` data type... now all the sudden you've turned it into a function that returns a `double`, and the argument being sent in is completely different from the original question...

Comment: @nhgrif I have answered in address to the OPs question and not just his code, I'll post an update with explanation for the change

Comment: Your answer still has problems.  For example, you're returning an `int` from a function you say returns a `double`... the same function which the OP wanted (or at least thought he wanted) to return `void`...

Comment: @nhgrif hey! I've updated it. Let me know if you still feel something is wrong

Comment: Again, you still have problems.  Despite the method being `void` return, he's using `pass` by reference, so the value of `num`, where ever he called it from IS being modified... he maintains that value.  But you still don't explain why your method looks like this: `DOUBLE prod(/*etc*/) { int result /*do stuff*/ return result; }`.  You've declared the function to return a `double` and you're returning an `int`.

Comment: But the original question is dealing with `int`.  Why have you even introduced `double` at all in the first place?

Comment: @nhgrif it depends on the scenario, if the OP is sure he wont get a larger number, he can always make it an int - it's always better to get ready to handle larger numbers though, especially because the calculation includes a lot of multiplication

Comment: I still don't understand going to `double` though.  If `int` isn't big enough, he should use `long`, and if that's not big enough, he should use `BigInteger`.  There's no reason for him to go to a floating point data type.  (in fact, he's already using `long` in the original question)

Comment: @nhgrif double is a primitive type, BigInteger is not

Comment: That's fine.  But `double` is a floating point data type, where `int` and `long` are not.  There's no justifiable reason for using `double` here when the original poster clearly wants to use a `long`.  If `long` isn't big enough, then he should use `BigInteger` before using `double`.  A `double` may hold a "larger" number than a  `long`, but it won't hold more digits of precision than a `long`.

Comment: @nhgrif please confirm before making a statement -_- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/44774

Comment: Err... that link is broken.  You can ignore my comments about `BigInteger`... that's a `Java` thing.  But no matter the language, there's a HUGE different between `double` and `int` or `double` and `long` (or `long long`).  You shouldn't just use `double` just because `int` won't hold a big enough number.

Comment: @nhgrif link fixed, the OP will judge that

Comment: I really don't think you understand the difference between integer and floating point data types.  Compare how `double`s behave with `/` division versus how a `long` behaves.  Compare how the behave with `%` modulus.  You have NO idea what the OP wants to do with this data.  You're changing him to `double` without a sufficient explanation (the only reason to change to a floating point data type is because you need to hold decimal places... fractional parts).

Comment: Consider that a `double` is 8-bytes.  4-bytes hold the significant digits, and the other 4-bytes hold the 10^n part.  Meanwhile a `long long` is ALSO 8-bytes, but all 8 are dedicated to the significant digits.  The upper and lower limits of a `long long` are less than the `upper and lower` limits of a `double` (which is practically unbound), but a `long long` has significantly more significant digits, and still behaves as an `int` when doing math like division and modulus (where the double absolutely doesn't).